# escape sequence while assigning style class to div in a label

Tags: c#, html, css, webforms

I came across a text assignment to a label in c# code. The code is

```
lbltext.text = string.format("<div class=\"test\">{0}</div>", "succesfully updated").
```

I'm using Label control and [documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.text?view=netframework-4.8) says:

> The Text property can include HTML. If it does, the HTML will be passed unchanged to the browser, where is might be interpreted as markup and not as text.

Even after reading it I don't understand what it is the purpose of using escape after "class=".

Is it like assigning the css class "test" to that div element?

If yes then why can't we do it like 'class="test"'?

Unable to find any answers googling. Can someone please clarify?.

Comment: Please [edit] post to include what stack you use (clearly not WebForms as you've said that there is nothing in documentation explaining this - so it is *not* WebForms' [Label](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.text?view=netframework-4.8) class).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it is a webforms label. The label is inside a user control.

Comment: I've updated the question to add tag and information from the docs that you already read. Please [edit] a bit more to clarify which part is confusing to you (as you was looking for html or CSS help based on tags)

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not 100% sure what this question is asking, but if it really is as simple as "why not just use class="test", then that would be because double quotes are used to describe literal strings. So What you would end up with would be

```
"<div class="   test    ">{0}</div>"
```

Which would cause a build error for starts. The escaping is done to allow double quotes to be used in a string without terminating the string early.

Worth noting that for classes, you can also you single quotes to get around this.

```
"<div class='test'>{0}</div>"
```

For Example :)